# RSI plot is larger than price plot (PineScript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Experts,

Having an issue with my first PineScript plots which is that the RSI plot is much larger than the price plot (see screenshot). Any idea how I can move the RSI plot to the bottom and make it smaller?

[image]

```
//@version=5
strategy("Simple MA Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000)

// Date range
startDate = timestamp(2000, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)

// Define inputs
ema1Value = input(title="EMA 1", defval=50)
ema1Source = input(title="EMA 1 Source", defval=close)
ema2Value = input(title="EMA 2",defval=200)
ema2Source = input(title="EMA 2 Source", defval=close)
rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length",defval=14)
rsiOverboughtLevel = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", defval=70)
rsiOversoldLevel = input(title="RSI Oversold Level", defval=30)

// Indicators
ema1 = ta.ema(ema1Source, ema1Value)
ema2= ta.ema(ema2Source, ema2Value)
rsi = ta.rsi(rsiSource,14)
rsiValue = ta.rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)

// Rules
ema_crossover = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
ema_crossunder = ta.crossunder(ema1, ema2)
isRsiOverbought = rsiValue >= rsiOverboughtLevel
isRsiOversold = rsiValue <= rsiOversoldLevel


// Plot indicators & levels
plot(ema1, color=color.green,linewidth = 1)
plot(ema2, color=color.fuchsia,linewidth = 1)

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=color.rgb(0, 18, 212))
rsiOversoldLine = hline(rsiOverboughtLevel, "OerSold", color=#C0C0C0)
rsiOverboughtLine = hline(rsiOversoldLevel, "OverBought", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(rsiOversoldLine, rsiOverboughtLine, color=color.rgb(147, 163, 208, 86), title="Background")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should plot the RSI in a different panel by using apposite `overlay` flag set to `false`.

```
strategy("Simple MA Strategy", overlay=false, initial_capital=10000)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but how can I plot other indicators like the EMA along with the price plot?

Comment: @checkmate711 you can't, you must create two separate indicators, one on the main panel and one on a new panel